# If statement is true OR not false

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean

I have two statements like this:

```
$ready = true;

if($ready === true) {
    echo "it's ready!";
}
```

And this:

```
$ready = true;

if($ready !== false) {
    echo "it's ready!";
}
```

I know those mean the same thing as `=== true` and `!== false` is the same thing. I see people use the negation type (is not false or is not {something}). like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4366748/4357238

But what are the pros and cons of using one or the other? Are there any performance benefits? Any coding benefits? I would think it is confusing to use the negation type rather than the straight forward `=== true`. Any input would be appreciated! thank you

Comment: `===true`, `!==false`, `==true` and `!=false` are actually four separate, distinct things.

Comment: @paulsm4 thank you but I know the difference between those. I was just asking if there was a difference in using double negatives of something (not false) rather than positive (true).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These do not mean the same thing, and you can see this demonstrated below:

```js
$ready = undefined;

if($ready === true) {
  console.log("it's ready 1");
}

if($ready !== false) {
  console.log("it's ready 2");
}
```

When in doubt, stick with `===`. You're comparing to exactly what it should be. "This should exactly be equal to true" vs "This should be equal to anything but exactly false" are 2 separate statements, the second including a lot of values that would be true (As demonstrated above, undefined is not exactly false, so this would be true).

Answer (score 1):

Most PHP functions return false as failure, such as `strpos`, from the manual it says:

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the
>   beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note
>   that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.

So it returns **an integer** or **false**, then it is wrong to use `strpos() === true`

`strpos() !== false` is the right way to check the result.

Answer (score 0):

It is not about performance and they are not the same. It helps us in reducing unnecessary if else statements.

Consider this: there is a variable `foobarbaz` whose value can be anything among **foo/ bar/ baz/ foobar/ barbaz.** You need to execute a statement if the value is not **foo**. So instead of writing like this:

```
if(foobarbaz === "bar" || foobarbaz === "baz" || foobarbaz === "foobar" || foobarbaz === "barbaz") {
    //some statement
}
else if(foobarbaz === "foo") {
    //do nothing
}
```

You can write something like this:

```
if(foobarbaz !== "foo") {
    //some statement
}
```

You can see we were able to eliminate the unnecessary else statement.

Answer (score 0):

In php == compare only the values are equal. For and example

$ready = 'true';

```
if($ready == true) {
    echo "true";
}
else{
    echo "false";
}
```

It print true.But if it is compare with === it not only check the values but also it check the datatype. So it compares with === it print the false.

Talking about !== it's work as the same. So it's not a problem to output if you use

```
if($ready === true)
```

or

```
if($ready !== false)
```

Can't compare these two because both are same.